# Saving a mat as greyscale image in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a std::vector and I convert it to a Mat with following:

```
mat = Mat(myVec).reshape(0, 64);
```

The values that I have in the vector are luminance values. I want to have a greyscale image with those values and save it. When I try following it saves as an RGB image.

```
imwrite(filePath, mat);
```

How can I do that? I tried like below but it is not giving the expected results.

```
cv::cvtColor(mat, greyMat, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
imwrite(filePath, greyMat);
```

Can someone please help with this?

Comment: From what you have here, it should work (without the cvtColor). What is the output of `mat.type()` and what do you mean by "not giving the expected results"?

Comment: @Paul92 mat.type() outputs 4. What does that mean? It does give write the image as a greyscale image because when I try to feed the written image to another program, it says it has 3 channels.

Comment: 4 means that is a single channel, 32 bit image. Are you reading it with `imread`? The deafult of imread is to read 3 channels.

Comment: @Paul92 sorry about the late reply. It is with Tensorflow that I am reading, not with OpenCV directly.